# Regex replace last (something)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a set of data which always contains something like this:

```
title(s) (some_text)
```

Now i would like to remove the (something) with regex.

My problem: The value in (some_text) can be anything.

Any idea how to solve this issue using regex?

**Some sample data:**

```
Egg(s) (whole) 
Berry (mix) (g)
```

**Expected output:**

```
Egg(s)
Berry (mix)
```

Comment: can you add sample data

Comment: Can you add a sample input and output please

Comment: Does `title(s)` literally mean the words `title` or `titles`?

Answer (score 0):

With `\s\(.*\)$` you can remove the last part of the data

Here the [example](https://regex101.com/r/3taY7C/1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your have each line in a separate string, you can use to match what should be removed:

[`\s*\([^(]*\)\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/KHKJ4j/1)

In a script:

```js
var tests = ["Egg(s) (whole) ", "Berry (mix) (g)"];
for (let s of tests) {
    s = s.replace(/\s*\([^(]*\)\s*$/, "");
    console.log(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'll do, using this regex `/\s\([^(]*\)$/`:

```js
var tests = ["Egg(s) (whole)", "Berry (mix) (g)"];
tests.forEach(function(str, i){
  tests[i] = str.replace(/\s\([^(]*\)$/, '');
});

console.log(tests);
```

You can't use the easier `/\s\(.*\)$/` as it will returns "Berry" for "Berry (mix) (g)".

Hope it helps.